# Messed up workspace - Where to start looking?

Tags: ros, setup.bash, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

I have the follwing problem:
I have the package `ar_track_alvar` installed via binary packages.
Also I have my own catkin-workspace.

Now, when I first source `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` followed by `my_workspace/devel/setup.bash`, I see all the included launch files, but only the `createMaker`-Node. All the other nodes wont autocomplete and when launch-files rely on them, they can't be found.

But when I source `opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` again, everything works as expected.

What might be the issue? Obviously something is wrong in my workspace, but I don't know where to begin looking.

---

Additional information:
In both cases I can autocomplete the package name, e.g. in `roscd ar_tr<tab>` to `ar_track_alvar`. Also in both cases I land in the same directory: `/opt/ros/hydro/share/ar_track_alvar`

Thanks in advance,

Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194943/messed-up-workspace---where-to-start-looking?/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First: Sourcing order does NOT matter. Whatever you source last should be active. So probably your workspace isn't build on hydro.

Under the assumption that you'd like to overlay the catkin workspace using hydro the following should fix that:

- Remove all build/devel/install dirs from the workspace
- `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`
- `catkin_make`

From now on: source `my_workspace/devel/setup.bash`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-10-14**:
Thanks, removing those 2 folders should have been the first obvious step. Solved my problem.